# Setting string with Arithmetic Operator in Mac Environment Variable

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, environment-variables

I am trying to environment variable in mac like

`export AUTH='FghygjhvjhgRT='`

But when I echo the above variable as `echo $[AUTH]` I am getting error like `-bash: FghygjhvjhgRT=: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "=")`

Comment: It's `echo "$AUTH"`.

Answer (score 1):

You likely didn't mean to use `$[...]`. You meant `${...}`:

```
$ echo ${AUTH}
FghygjhvjhgRT=
```

Comment: While for the current content of the variable, it works well, you should put in your solution the parameter between double quotes. Maybe the OP wants to use one day spaces in his authorization string.